# How can exact same value differ in math result only by changing type from int to decimal

Tags: c#, integer, decimal

I was working on some project and need to do some math :

```
decimal X = (Value / 881) * (item.Type ? 130: 130 * 2);
```

the param "Value" equals 3000 for example.

if "Value" is of type `int` the result is 390..
if "Value" is of type `decimal` the result is 442.67

how is this possible ??

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/09pIDw)

Comment: when `Value` is of type `int`, you have *integer division*: `Value / 881` which is `3000 / 881 == 3`; when `Value` is `decimal` then `3000m / 881 == 3.405...m`

Comment: The more *unprecise* (e.g. division which produce remainder) operations you do with `int`, the bigger is the accumulated error of the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of Decimal value. If you calculate your formula step by step you will understand this difference is due to values which are coming after decimal point when you are using `decimal` as a type

When you divide 3000(integer) by 881:

```
int Value = 3000
//Output is 3. Output is in integer
decimal X = (Value / 881);  //When int is divided by int then result is in int
```

When you divide 3000(decimal) by 881:

```
decimal Value = 3000
//Output is 3.4052213393870601589103291714. Output is in decimal.
decimal X = (Value / 881);  //When decimal is divided by int then result is in decimal
```

[.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K2BN5w)

I hope .net fiddle will give you a better idea of my answer